# Transform int column in checkbox in DatagridView

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datagridview

I'm using DatagridView with Entity Framework and i want to import my database to a DatagridView.

Code:

```
gv.DataSource = myContext.myTable.ToList<myTable>();
```

One of my fields is a int, but i want to make it a turn on/off button (red circle/green circle), or simplifying a checkbox.

How can i transform a already importated (via EF) int column to a checkbox column?

PS: I have Devcomponent components, but i don't need to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the column type to BIT that would do it.

Comment: You would change the database column to type BIT so that EF would automatically cast it as a Boolean

Comment: I don't create columns, just bind the EF to DataSource. If i create a column with the same name as Boolean, the EF creates another column with the same name and type int. :/